# Битрикс. Свойство инфоблока типа ключ-значение

Tags: битрикс

Привет! Есть такая задача, сделать веб интерфейс для отправки смс. Грубо говоря есть поле текста и поле для нескольких номеров. По нажатию на кнопку методом POST отправляется сообщение в виде: `номер:текст`, в ответ приходит `ID` сообщения. Как мне сделать хранение в инфоблоке информации `ID:номер` в рамках одного элемента?

Comment: вам точно нужно использовать инфоблоки?

Comment: @Mihanik71, да, ведь мне нужно хранить информацию об отправленных сообщениях

Comment: Лучше использовать для этих целей Highload блоки. Но если уж нужно использовать свойство инфоблока, то я бы создавал на всякий случай множественное свойство `PROPERTY_PHONE`, которому в значение бы ставил номер телефона, а в `XML_ID` полученный ID. Так правильнее с точки зрения архитектуры, как мне кажется.

Comment: @НиколайСарры что такое `XML_ID` где почитать об этом подробней?

Comment: `XML_ID` существует у свойств типа "список". В принципе по такой аналогии можно создать и собственный тип "ключ-значение".

Comment: @НиколайСарры а как в такое свойство заносить данные программно? В документации в функции CIBlockElement::Add вообще ничего не сказано про свойство "Список"

Answer (score 1):

Если в инфоблоке хранить нужно, то:

1. Необходимо создать свойство «номер телефона» (PROPERTY_PHONE)
2. На странице пишем обработчик который будет добавлять элемент.

Код обработчика:

```
<?
    if(isset($_REQUEST["phone"]) && isset($_REQUEST["mess"]) ){
    $el = new CIBlockElement;

    $PROP = array();
    $PROP["PHONE"] = $_REQUEST["phone"];  // свойству с кодом 12 присваиваем значение "Белый"   

    $arLoadProductArray = Array(
        "MODIFIED_BY"    => $USER->GetID(), // элемент изменен текущим пользователем
        "IBLOCK_SECTION_ID" => false,          // элемент лежит в корне раздела
        "IBLOCK_ID"      => 18,//указать свой
        "PROPERTY_VALUES"=> $PROP,
        "NAME"           => "Элемент",
        "ACTIVE"         => "Y",            // активен
        "DETAIL_TEXT"   => $_REQUEST["mess"],
    );

    if($PRODUCT_ID = $el->Add($arLoadProductArray))
      echo $PRODUCT_ID;
    else
      echo "Error: ".$el->LAST_ERROR;
}?>
```

Но для Вашей задачи лучше использовать «Highload-блоки» [подробнее](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=43&CHAPTER_ID=05745)

Comment: т.е. получается номер телефона лежит в свойстве, а ID в полной новости? Мне же надо так хранить несколько, не одну, пару `ID:номер`, для этой цели мне кажется это не совсем подходит

Comment: Ну Вы можете для каждого номера создать свой элемент, а можете свойство PHONE сделать множественным и записывать все варианты